# Copy Constructor with Heap Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to make a pointer call the copy constructor on creation but keep referencing the object instead it seems. Is what I'm doing completely wrong then.

```
Queue<int> * a = new Queue<int>();
Queue<int> * b = a;
```

This keeps referring to a instead of using the copy constructor which works fine on stack allocated objects.

Comment: Remember that C++ is not Java and you don't need to use heap-allocated objects all the time. You should prefer object with automatic life-time (allocation on the stack).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't call copy constructors through pointers like that.

To call the copy constructor you need to be more explicit:

```
Queue< int >* b = new Queue< int >( *a );
```

Comment: Thank you, my c++ has become a bit rusty, I couldn't remember how to do that.